# backup-restore without permissions

Tags: permissions, backup

I want to restore backup from production environment to dev/test environment to get latest content from production environment. User/groups who have permissions on production are totally different than users in dev/test environment. I don't want to copy permissions from production to test/dev, is it possible to do with any SharePoint backup method.
If it is not possible is there any easy way to regenerate permissions on dev/test which were there before restore, any scripts or code techniques?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `export-spweb / import-spweb` which by default will not carry over user security settings.

Command reference:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607895(v=office.15).aspx